# Why do we find eigen vectors of the co-variance matrix in PCA?

Tags: machine-learning, linear-algebra

In PCA,why is finding the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of the covariance matrix of the data equivalent of fitting  principal-component lines to the variance of the data?

I have understood eigen vectors in terms of matrix transformation.But why do eigen vectors of the co-variance matrix of the data give us the lines which express maximum variance?